# Python - Unable to read latest data from database

Tags: database, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a Django application writing to sqlite3 database, which is immediately accessed by Python scripts on the same machine.

I want the python scripts to be able to read the last entry that the Django application has submitted.

### Scenario

1. User logs in Django website from Raspberry Pi (RPi)
2. User enters desired data.
3. Data submitted to database.
4. User pushes push button connected to RPi, which prompts database query.
5. Separate python scripts perform calculations based on user input.

I am sure that the Django app writes to the database **before** I am trying to access this data from the python scripts. I am using `sqiltebrowser` to check this.

### Database:

```
       tact   
----------------- 
        45        <- old value retrieved     
        60        <- new value not retrieved   
        60        <- new value not retrieved
```

### Code:

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Line3_Data.db')
    conn.commit()
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT tact FROM LineOEE03 ORDER BY tact desc limit 1")
    current_tact = c.fetchone()
    print(current_tact) #prints 45
```

I am aware that `conn.commit()` should get my session up to date, but why is this not the case here?

Comment: any query is not being passed to conn for updating e.g. conn.cursor().execute("UPDATE myTable SET yourField= 2")
conn.commit()

Comment: What is `SETyourField=2` referring to please?